# Insert text surrounded by angular brackets inside contenteditable div?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a content editable div which is my search box. I need to add stack trace in C which has memory addresses surrounded by angular braces. When I insert this text inside the search box, it is being considered as html tags. How should I avoid that ?

An example of the content I am pasting inside the div:

```
[<ffffffff810733ff>] do_exit+0x15f/0x870
[<ffffffff8109dc25>] ? sched_clock_local+0x25/0x90
[<ffffffff81088792>] ? __dequeue_signal+0x102/0x200
[<ffffffff81073b68>] do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
```

The div element after pasting.

```
<div id="searchBox" 
contenteditable="true">do_exit+0x15f/0x870[<ffffffff8109dc25>] ?
sched_clock_local+0x25/0x90[<ffffffff81088792>] ?
__dequeue_signal+0x102/0x200[<ffffffff81073b68>] do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please? A typical contenteditable element won't do what you're describing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attribute `contenteditable` + unofficial value `"plaintext-only"` already answered.

Beside if you copy/paste these, brackets are turned into html entities.

If this is already in your code, then you should treat this on server side.

Anyway here is an extra option, if you still want to use html tag around this bits of code, you may give a try to an old tag [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp):

What says W3C about it : https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/xmp ... use at your own appreciation.

```html
<div id="searchBox" 
contenteditable="true"><xmp>do_exit+0x15f/0x870[<ffffffff8109dc25>] ?
sched_clock_local+0x25/0x90[<ffffffff81088792>] ?
__dequeue_signal+0x102/0x200[<ffffffff81073b68>] do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
  </xmp></div>
```

---

**the proper way would be :** (use htmlentities() or similar to treat brackets before being send to browser or when saved ).

```css
[contenteditable] {
  white-space:pre;
  }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">do_exit+0x15f/0x870[&lt;ffffffff8109dc25&gt;] ?
  sched_clock_local+0x25/0x90[&lt;ffffffff81088792&gt;] ? 
  __dequeue_signal+0x102/0x200[ffffffff81073b68&gt;] do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers support `contenteditable="plaintext-only"`, which solves your problem. However, the browsers that don’t support this may not even make the div contenteditable.

Example:

```
<div contenteditable="plaintext-only"></div>
```

---

A better solution to this problem would probably to use a native `<input>` or `<textarea>` — those should handle this for you.

Comment: I am on chrome and It still considers it as a html element.